# in SpringBoot 2.x(2.1.0) the custom filter process once but produce duplicated data

Tags: spring-boot, filter

I'm new in using SpringBoot 2.1.0 with JSP (with some reasons) to develop web applications.

I'm using a filter to save access info into the database, which are mapping to one type of url.
But there're some **problems**:
1. When I click the link on a menu, the page is new opened in the browser, but logs output twice, it's indicate that **doFilterInternal** method executed twice, this situation is NOT correct;

```
2018-12-13 13:43:07.405  WARN 14912 --- [nio-8096-exec-2] c.y.l.c.filters.rpt.AccessMenuFilter     : ---------------------------- Access Once ----------------------------------------
2018-12-13 13:43:07.405  WARN 14912 --- [nio-8096-exec-3] c.y.l.c.filters.rpt.AccessMenuFilter     : ---------------------------- Access Once ----------------------------------------
```

2. Then I right click the mouse on opened page in step one, and choose refresh the iframe, logs output only once, it's indicate that **doFilterInternal** method executed once, this situation is correct, in step one it should execute once too.

```
2018-12-13 13:44:02.118  WARN 14912 --- [nio-8096-exec-1] c.y.l.c.filters.rpt.AccessMenuFilter     : ---------------------------- Access Once ----------------------------------------
```

[insert two records into Database in step one, one record in step two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDhbl.jpg)

The filter extends to **OncePerRequestFilter**, see from other posts, it may causes the call twice, but why in step 2 the filter call once.

I post the main codes below:

**POM.xml**
https://github.com/richard20427176/pom-config/blob/master/pom.xml

Below is main of **SpringBootConfig** code:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class SpringBootConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
//        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false); 
        configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
                .favorParameter(true)
                .parameterName("format")
                .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xls", MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
                .mediaType("xlsx", MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        Set<String> modelKeys=new HashSet<>();
        modelKeys.add("list");
        modelKeys.add("table");

        registry.jsp("/views/", ".jsp");
        registry.enableContentNegotiation(new MappingJackson2JsonView());

        XlsView xlsView=new XlsView();
        xlsView.setModelKeys(modelKeys);
        registry.enableContentNegotiation(xlsView);

        XlsxView xlsxView=new XlsxView();
        xlsxView.setModelKeys(modelKeys);
        registry.enableContentNegotiation(xlsxView);
    }
}
```

And below is **Filter Config** code:

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean shiroDelegatingFilterProxy() {
        DelegatingFilterProxy proxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        proxy.setTargetFilterLifecycle(true);
        proxy.setTargetBeanName("shiroFilter");

        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(proxy);

        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

The last, below is implement of the **Filter** code:

```
@Component
public class AccessMenuFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessMenuFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private MonitorService monitorService;
    @Autowired
    private MenuService menuService;
    private Set<MenuIsMonitorVo> monitorMenus=new HashSet<>();
    private Map<String, RequestMatcher> menuRequestMatcherMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String pageNumber = request.getParameter(Page.PAGE_NUMBER_REQUEST_PARAM_NAME);
            // If page no greater than 2, then skip
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(pageNumber) || pageNumber.compareTo("1")<=0) {
                for(Map.Entry<String,RequestMatcher> entry:menuRequestMatcherMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue().matches(request)) {

                        String username = ShiroBaseService.getLoginUser().getUsername();

                        UserAgent userAgent=UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT));
                        String browser= WebUtil.getBrowserName(userAgent);

                        CreateAccessMenuDto createAccessMenuDto = new CreateAccessMenuDto();
                        createAccessMenuDto.setMenuId(entry.getKey());
                        createAccessMenuDto.setUserName(username);
                        createAccessMenuDto.setOsName(userAgent.getOperatingSystem().getName());
                        createAccessMenuDto.setBrowserName(browser);
                        createAccessMenuDto.setIpAddress(RemoteIpHelper.getRemoteIpFrom(request));
                        createAccessMenuDto.setRequestLocale(request.getLocale().getDisplayName());
                        createAccessMenuDto.setCreateTime(new Date());

                        monitorService.asyncCreateAccessMenu(createAccessMenuDto);

                        LOGGER.warn("---------------------------- Access Once ----------------------------------------");

                        LOGGER.debug("Successfully add user access log:[SessionId:{};Username:{};platform:{};Browser:{};IPAddress:{};MenuId:{}]. The request url is {}",
                                request.getSession(false).getId(),
                                username,
                                userAgent.getOperatingSystem().getName(),
                                browser,
                                RemoteIpHelper.getRemoteIpFrom(request),
                                entry.getKey(),
                                request.getRequestURL());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("User Access fail due to the reason:"+ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {
        if (monitorMenus != null && monitorMenus.size() > 0) {
            RequestMatcher matcher;
            for (MenuIsMonitorVo menu : monitorMenus) {
                if (menu.getIsMonitor().equals("1")) {
                    String pattern = menu.getMenuUrl();
                    if (!pattern.startsWith("/")) {
                        pattern = "/" + pattern;
                    }
                    if (pattern.indexOf("?") != -1) {
                        pattern = pattern.substring(0, pattern.indexOf("?"));
                    }

                    LOGGER.info("Add menu[MenuId:{},pattern:{}] to access log monitor candidate map.", menu.getMenuId(), pattern);

                    matcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern);
                    menuRequestMatcherMap.put(menu.getMenuId(), matcher);
                }
            }
        } else {
            monitorMenus = menuService.menuIsMonitor().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me and thanks very much.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the OPTIONS requests are doing those extra filter invocations for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS It should be visible in the network tab of your browser.

Comment: [Lakatos Gyula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420715/lakatos-gyula) you're right, I use bTabs.js and pym.v1.js in the JSP file, there's some conflict, pym.v1.js change the request path from menu in a short time and then request again.    Change the js code is OK. Thanks very much~

Comment: I'm glad that you was able to fix it! :) I posted an answer about this. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure that the OPTIONS requests are doing those extra filter invocations for you.

Please check http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS for more information. It should be visible in the network tab of your browser.